# Passing parameter as variable in Run function

Tags: autoit

as the title says, here is my code but its not working

```
; Get the parameter from open file dialog
GUICtrlSetData($locationtxt, FileOpenDialog("Select the program", '', "Supported files (*.exe;*.msi;*.reg;*.inf)|Executable Files (*.exe)|Microsoft Installer files (*.msi)|Registry files (*.reg)|Inf files (*.inf)", 3))

; store the value in a variable 
 $abc = GUICtrlRead($locationtxt)
 ; Run the program and pass the parameter value
            Run("ussf.exe "  & $abc  )

  ; If i do it this way, its working but i want the parameter value from the open dialog not fixed
  Run("ussf.exe C:\Users\project\ccsetup563.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for Run() is the working directory, not an argument for the program. I think you should be using ShellExecute(), or ShellExecuteWait() instead.